# Making Partial Views truly reusable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

My goal is to create a partial view that can be used in dozens of other views, across an MVC application.  This partial view will accept data from the parent View's model for use as its model.

My problem is that I don't know how to send this data from the parent view's model to the partial view.  Here is some code:

PARENT VIEW'S MODEL CLASS:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public GlobalPartialView GPV { get; set; }
}
```

PARTIAL VIEW'S MODEL CLASS:

```
public class GlobalPartialView
{
    public string PartialViewString { get; set; }
}
```

PARENT VIEW:

```
@model TestMVC_CRUD.Models.TestModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>


<div>
    <div>ID: @Model.ID</div>
    <div>Name: @Model.Name</div>
</div>

@Html.Partial("_GlobalPartialView", Model.GPV);
```

PARTIAL VIEW:

```
@model TestMVC_CRUD.Models.GlobalPartialView

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "View1";
}

<h2>View1</h2>

<div>Value: @Model.PartialViewString</div>
```

This code does not work.  The partial view will not accept Model.GPV as its model.

How does one send a sub object from the parent View's model to a partial view for use as its model?  Also, if there is a better way to accomplish this, I would love to hear it.

Comment: Erm, why don't you just create a `~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/GlobalPartialView.cshtml` file, then call `@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.GPV)`? Also, if you're trying to store HTML in the `PartialViewString` you're going to need to use `Html.Raw`.

Comment: This code should work. What is the actual result you are getting? Did you populate the `GPV` property of the main view model when you rendered the parent view? Coz if you left this property `null` it's pretty obvious that you're gonna get a NRE in your partial because the model you have passed is null and inside your partial you are trying to access `@Model.PartialViewString` <=> `null.PartialViewString` which you know what would be the result of.

Comment: Darin- that fixed it.  It seems like I was having additional trouble using the kind of architecture, however.  I will research the past issues further and post them.  Brad- I will try that.  Thank you both.

Answer (score 1):

This code should work. It looks like you forgot to populate the `GPV` property of the main view model when you rendered the parent view. And you simply got a NRE because you partial view is accessing `@Model.PartialViewString`.

Make sure that the controller action that is rendering your parent view is actually populating the `GPV` property:

```
var model = new TestModel();
model.GPV = new GlobalPartialView();
model.GPV.PartialViewString = "The foo bar";
return View(model);
```